# Internet Explorer 9 Not Displaying Text Properly

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, web, cross-browser

I am working on a website and doing some testing in IE9.

I have a slideshow section. 
Some look like this (correctly displayed): https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbcP5.jpg
And others look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXEMU.jpg

The button is cut off and the last name from the quote doesn't display. I have narrowed down my issue to be due to the amount of words used in my h2. In other browsers such as Chrome it somehow makes all the words fit and keeps the same font-size. How do I make this work in IE9?

Comment: Images do nothing. Real working code is needed. Also IE7?? Was that a typo?

Comment: Yes. Sorry. That was a typo. I ended up solving the problem. My conditional CSS was only affecting versions less than IE9. I just needed to make it less than or equal to IE9 and I was able to fix the issue by increasing the width of my container to fit the text. Thanks everyone for the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be due to varying default user agent stylesheets. Using a CSS reset, like [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/), may help you achieve consistency, all else being equal.

You may want to use the old [1.1.3 branch](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/tree/857aa8bfd433a8b0457b4df6ac882dc072d37220) of normalize because you require IE7 support.

Note that IE7 usage is [basically nil](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version_partially_combined-ww-monthly-201311-201411-bar), I recommend dropping support for it.

Comment: I just tried using normalize.css and still getting the same issue.

Comment: It could be a layout issue too. Maybe you are using floats irresponsibly. Tables are much easier to use in legacy IE, you may want to try that.

Comment: Nope. Still the same. Very frustrating. Backwards compatibility in IE is a nightmare.

Comment: Yeah. I'm not going to bother with IE7. Doing testing in IE9 now (edited my post). Still same issue. Bizarre.